# Настройка bridge-интерфеса для виртуализации

Tags: debian, виртуализация, kvm

Хочу установить виртуальную машину на Debian 8 и сделал ее как сервер. Использую эту инструкцию - [Howto Qemu-kvm Debian 8](https://habrahabr.ru/post/260791/)

Дохожу до того, что надо прописать что-то в ***/etc/network/interfaces***. Первый раз, когда я там прописал что-то - пропал коннект к серверу.

Что там прописать, чтобы работал и основной сервер, и виртуалка?

там сейчас такое:

```
# Loopback device:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# device: eth0
auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address   213.239.197.111
netmask   255.255.255.224
gateway   213.239.197.97
# default route to access subnet
up route add -net 213.239.197.96 netmask 255.255.255.224 gw 213.239.197.97 eth0

iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2a01:4f8:130:622e::2
netmask 64
gateway fe80::1
```

Comment: *что там прописать* — целиком и полностью зависит от того, что там «прописано» сейчас. приведите, пожалуйста, содержимое этого файла прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вообще-то для того, чтобы «заработала виртуализация», никаких изменений в файл `/etc/network/interfaces` вносить не нужно. после установки *libvirt-bin* (и зависимых от него пакетов) будет создан bridge-интерфейс, к которому и будут подключаться виртуальные машины, и будет настроен nat-доступ для виртуальных машин к «внешнему миру».

если вам потребуется доступ из внешнего мира к виртуальным машинам, можно воспользоваться «пробросом портов» или проксированием.

---

но если вас это по каким-то причинам не устраивает, вы можете, конечно, объединить в bridge (к которому будут подключаться виртуальные машины) и ваш физический сетевой интерфейс *eth0*.

для этого надо внести такие изменения в `/etc/network/interfaces`:

1. замените **все** упоминания строки `eth0` на строку `br0` во всём файле
2. добавьте в самом начале файла или, например, после строки `iface lo inet loopback`, строку `iface eth0 inet manual`
3. сразу после строки `iface br0 inet static` добавьте те строки, что рекомендует автор используемого вами руководства:

   ```
   bridge_ports eth0
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_fd 0
   bridge_maxwait 0
   ```
4. ничего не могу подсказать по поводу *ipv6* (четыре строки, начиная с `iface br0 inet6 static`).

после этого имеет смысл перезагрузить сервер.

а при последующей установке пакета *libvirt-bin*, насколько помню, должен быть задан вопрос, какой bridge-интерфейс следует использовать для подключения виртуальных машин. понятно, что надо будет выбрать созданный вами интерфейс *br0*.

Comment: спасибо, вы очень помогли

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Comment: да, спасибо. еще бы узнать как на виртуалку OS поставить и подключится к ней удаленно